# Android: trying to use html img or Webview causes me problems

Tags: android, android-webview

hi I'm trying to load up a html file via a Custom Alert box, to take advantage of formatting. but my app crashes when ever I launch the dialog. I had a problem yesterday too when I was just using html string conversion, I could get things like bold text working, but couldn't encourage it to use an image file located in my root/assets folder. I wonder if its a code error or am I referencing my assets folder incorrectly. I know it sounds like two problems but I'm hoping they are related?

I've tried with and without the JS true, there is no js in my html file, and its very basic.

```
     WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
     mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/helppage.html");
```

Error Dump

```
 03-24 14:20:59.800: W/dalvikvm(5574): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at com.mediabar.timelapse.TimeLapseActivity.createDialog(TimeLapseActivity.java:140)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at com.mediabar.timelapse.TimeLapseActivity$3.onClick(TimeLapseActivity.java:66)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
03-24 14:20:59.800: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: Added activity

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_left_in, R.anim.push_right_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button help = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
        help.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createDialog();
            }

        });     
    }

    public void createDialog() {

         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CopyOfTimeLapseActivitybackup.this);

         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.help_dialog);
         dialog.setTitle("Help Area");

         WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
         mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/helppage.html");

         Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
         button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                   dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });

         dialog.show(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is 140th of your `TimeLapseActivity` class?

Comment: thats mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/helppage.html"); and thank you for pointing out the line ref. I'm very new to Java and eclipse and find it very hard to fault find at the moment.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you will get NPE on this line. If it was the one above it, then it might have been that the webView was not properly initialized. However, this line seems pretty ok, and yes you are referencing the assets folder correctly

Comment: I dont know if I should be happy or sad.

Comment: Is the WebView part of a dialog? If so you probably need to call findViewById() on the dialogs view, rather than from your activity's context.

Comment: Can you add more code. Also do you mean it is the line you pointed at if you exclude the `mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` from the code (if so then it still might be the case that the web view is null).

Comment: Aha, then really your web view is null. This means that the id.webview is not defined in your context. Where is web view defined? I assume it is in the dialog and @Tim is completely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

to look like this:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

You have to do it this way because your webview's parent is the dialog, not your Activity layout.

I think you might also have to move all of your findViewById() calls to after the `dialog.show();`

Comment: hey nice one. thats done the trick. I'm not sure what you last line meant, I tried with dialog.show() at the top and the bottom and both worked? I would assume this command would be final, but I'm usually wrong! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the below line will work for your, just read whole html file and store it into a string variable and add below life

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", 'your string variable here', "text/html",
                "utf-8", "");
```